# Can I use the word "trovi" for opinions?

Tags: verbs

In some languages, the verb "to find" is used figuratively to express opinions.

- I find this house beatiful.
- Back then, I found it impossible to succeed.
- How do you find this design?

Is this possible in Esperanto?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible. The seventh meaning of *trovi* in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#trovi) is the following:

> Opinii ion aŭ iun ia

Comment: That doesn't stop people from telling you that you can't. I ignore those people.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Right, I don't see your point… The asker never mentioned that someone told them they could not use *trovi* thusly, nor did my answer indicate that people tend to do that.

Comment: My point was to agree with you - and to preemptively disagree with anybody who disagrees. This is a moderately common question and you'll occasionally find people who are going around trying to "correct" this error which is not an error.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander That makes sense. Thanks :). Though considering I referenced a very unambiguous quote from PIV I doubt anyone is going to contradict me here. I appreciate the initiative, but upvoting my answer suffices if you agree with me :p.

Comment: You have my upvote. As for people disagreeing with PIV, it happens.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Lovely :), thanks! Hm, interesting… I haven't seen people disagreeing with PIV thus far, but it seems that I might!

Comment: I have decided that the question of whether people question PIV warrants it's own question - so I have posted one along with an answer.